Where did the energy created go if there are no non-conservative forces like friction acting in my scenario?
In my scenario, there is a string (which is elastic and massless) which is tied tightly to a wall and other end is fixed to a machine which can create waves without human error. If half wave with positive amplitude is sent through the string with some speed. It hits the wall and reflects back with same speed and negative amplitude. When it is about to come back to initial place, another half wave with negative amplitude is made to pass through that  string such that the two half waves interfere destructively at all times. The two half waves interfere destructively at all times, so that the kinetic energy is zero for that string  and there is no string potential energy. In this case there are no non conservative forces like friction to act on the system, but only the waves are created in such a way that they are  destructive at all times , then where did the all the initial energy given to the string go.

I am giving a little bit clarity about my scenario in the diagram given above

What about the other end of the string?

It is fixed to machine which can create waves exactly without human error

Yes, then (as an answer already said) the machine will take the impact of the incident wave. Now what happens depends on what you want to happen.

I don't think that you can have a wave in a massless string. So I will ignore that bit.

If half wave with positive amplitude is sent through the string with some speed. ... another half wave with negative amplitude is made to pass through that string

The process of making the first half wave involves some external source providing energy to the string. The process of making the second half wave involves some external source extracting energy from the string.

The two half waves interfere destructively at all times, so that the kinetic energy is zero for that string and there is no way we and there is no string potential energy. In this case there are no non conservative forces like friction to act on the system, but only the waves are created in such a way that they are destructive at all times , then where did the all the initial energy given to the string go.

It went back into the source.
One thing that may be confusing you about your own description is your stipulation that the KE is zero. That cannot be achieved by sending an inverted wave along the string. That can only be achieved by absorbing the energy at a source. If you simply send an inverted wave then at the moment when the waves cancel out the string does have KE.

does that mean creating a half wave with negative amplitude is equivalent to absorbing energy from the system

It depends critically on when you do it. If you do it at the time that the other wave arrives, then yes. If you do it at another time then you don’t get the KE = 0 situation

If it is not done at that time ,then does that mean we are giving energy to string

Yes, and there will not be KE = 0

If the "+ wave" and "– wave" are traveling in opposite directions, there will be a moment when the string is flat as they pass through each other and cancel, but then they will continue past each other as before. The string still has kinetic energy during the pass through – it just happens to occupy a position equivalent to "no wave."
